# Sikuli error in c# with Sikuli integrator package

Tags: c#, selenium, sikuli

When I run this code:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using Sikuli4Net.sikuli_REST;
using Sikuli4Net.sikuli_UTIL;
using SikuliModule;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Sikuli
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
          driver = new ChromeDriver();
          driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
          driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.co.nz/");
          Thread.Sleep(2000);
          String image = @"C:\Users\safa\Desktop\gmail.jpg";
          SikuliAction.Click(image);
        }

    }
}
```

I got this exception:

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception:
'The system cannot find the file specified'
```

I changed file location but again I got same error.
This the image that I want to click on:
[image]

Comment: Please include the code of this method: `SikuliAction.Click(image)`.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get what  you mean exactly but I edited the program.

Comment: How can anyone help you finding an issue with your code if you do not include it? The error you are having occurring inside `SikuliAction.Click()`. It will be very helpful to see the actual implementation of this method.

Comment: I uninstalled JRE 64 bit and installed JRE 32 bit and it solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

Run the visual studio as administrator using below steps

1. Click on start(windows) button
2. Type Visual Studio
3. Mouse Right Click on Visual Studio
4. Click on Run as Administrator option

I think there is no mistakes in code. So try this once.

Increase the wait time to 5000ms

For this program you don't need Sikuli4Net, remove usings related to that